# How to rsync exclude directory and subdirectories Multiple

Tags: command-line, permissions, lubuntu, backup, rsync

I want exclude multiple directory and subdirectories and its contents files.

I want to transfer(send) all folder and file from `/home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html`

**But want to exclude these directories and their subdir with all files. they have some random dir names**

```
/home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/admin/data/engine/storage
/home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/admin/smarty/cache
/home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/admin/data/conversion
/home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/contents/
/home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/contents/548/
/home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/contents/8fd63uu47/
/home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/contents/95ued/
```

I have try two way:

```
rsync -avPh /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html --exclude={'backup/*/*','conversion/*/*','smarty/cache/*/*','storage/*/*','contents/*/*'} ubuntu@000.00.00.00:/home/ubuntu
```

and:

```
rsync -avPh /home/admin/web/domainn.com/public_html --exclude={'/backup/*','/conversion/*','/cache/*','/storage/*/*','/contents/*'} ubuntu@000.00.00.00:/home/ubuntu
```

Comment: download luckyBackup from the Ubuntu Software Center. It will allow you to make numerous selections and if you need to have it for terminal commands, youo will be able to see what those commands are within the package

Comment: With a large number of items to exclude, it will be more practical to use the `exclude-from=` option. You then put the file name patterns of all directories you want to exclude in a text file, and have `rsync` read the list from that text file.

Comment: Hi @vanadium I think, I found the solution, this way `storage/**/*.dat` but its taking time to exclude, How about if create txt file and exclude-from does this option have more speed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this command?

```
rsync -avPh /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html --exclude={'admin/data/conversion', 'admin/smarty/cache', 'contents'} ubuntu@000.00.00.00:/home/ubuntu
```

Comment: If you're using brace expansion, you shouldn't have spaces after the `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Applying “what I did” to “what I'd do were I you,”

```
cd /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html
find . "$DIR" -type d > exclude_list.txt
```

to get a full, recursive list of ALL underlying directories. Why `find?` Because it not as unwieldy as `ls` seems to be.

Then edit the `exclude_list.txt` file so it has the relative directory names on each line, dumping those you want backup.

(The brain teaser is that the `exclude_list` lists the directories to skip, so seeing it here means you won't see it there, and levels of opposite logic or conditions makes my head hurt, then explode. It gets worse if you comment out a line—to skip it from being excluded—so commenting out a line INCLUDES that line's directory in the `rsync` backup, but I digress. <cleaning up scattered grey matter…>)

```
admin/data/engine/storage
admin/smarty/cache
admin/data/conversion
contents/
contents/548/
contents/8fd63uu47/
contents/95ued/
etc…
```

There may be other paths peppered in. The script to run has been `chmod`ed to execute, and looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -vra --exclude-from='exclude-file.txt' 'source_dir' 'dest_dir'
```

Switches are for

```
-v verbose
-r recursive, -a supposedly implies and includes this too
-a which includes the -r switch and others as well
```

What got me was that the format of the exclude_file needs to be in relative directory name format, not absolute format. I experimented with that a bit on some test directories before I figured it out.